# Passing object to the function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass object as a variable to the function in this scenario? I'm getting console.log(setup) = undefined? Is there any better way to pass callback function to getTemplate() ? Thanks

Function Template

```
function getTemplate (name, callback, dir) {
          if (dir === undefined) dir = ''
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
          var url = '/core/templates/' + dir + name + '.html'
          xhr.open('GET', url, true)
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              var raw = xhr.responseText
              var compiled = Handlebars.compile(raw)
              callback(compiled)
            }
          }
          xhr.send()
        }
```

Calling Function

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
 var tabActive = ''
 if (i == 0) { tabActive = 'active' }

 var tab = item[i],
 tabId = tab.id,
 tabTitle = tab.title,
 variables = {tabActive: tabActive, tabId: tab.id, tabTitle: tab.title}

 console.log(variables) // *A increments 5328, 5329

 getTemplate('tab-nav', function (tmp) {

 console.log(variables) // *B increments 5328, 5328

 $(tabNavigationId + '>ul').append(tmp(variables))

 })

}
```

*A

```
index.js:18 Object {tabActive: "active", tabId: "5327", tabTitle: "User Experience"}
index.js:18 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5328", tabTitle: "Design"}
index.js:18 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5329", tabTitle: "Web Development"}
index.js:18 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5330", tabTitle: "Mobile Development"}
```

*B

```
index.js:21 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5743", tabTitle: "Extension Settings"}
index.js:21 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5743", tabTitle: "Extension Settings"}
index.js:21 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5743", tabTitle: "Extension Settings"}
index.js:21 Object {tabActive: "", tabId: "5743", tabTitle: "Extension Settings"}
```

Callback from getTemplate 'tmp'

```
function ret(context, execOptions) {
        if (!compiled) {
          compiled = compileInput();
        }
        return compiled.call(this, context, execOptions);
      }
```

Comment: Most probably your `getTemplate` function is not properly passing the required arguments. Can you show the code of your `getTemplate` function?

Comment: Your parameter named `setup` is shading the global (or higher-scoped in any case) variable named `setup`

Comment: I've added getTemplate() to the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass your variable in the callback function.

You need to use it as

```
var setup = {tabActive: tabActive, tabId: tab.id, tabTitle: tab.title}

getTemplate('tab-nav', function (tmp) {
  //setup is accessible here
  console.log(setup)
  $(tabNavigationId + '>ul').append(tmp(setup))
})
```

-- New UPDATE --

Your getTemplate function `function getTemplate (name, callback, dir) {`
expects 2nd parameter to be a callback function.
So what you need to do is, use the getTemplate function as

```
getTemplate('tab-nav', myCallBackFunc, 'dir');
```

then the `myCallBackFunc` will be something like this.

I can see that you are calling the callback with some parameter.

```
function myCallBackFunc(response) {
 //do something with response
}
```

Also you haven't defined anything about `tmp` function

Comment: if I do that the variables with function(tmp) does not increment

Comment: @Raf can you share your whole code in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I can't use fiddle as the code uses local template from the file. Check it now I've added more code to it.

Comment: @Raf Please try console.log(tmp) and share the output. inside , function(tmp) {

Comment: @HariLamichhane I've added console log output now

Comment: @HariLamichhane tmp returns a function listed above which expects me to pass the object {tabActive: tabActive, tabId: tab.id, tabTitle: tab.title}

Comment: @HariLamichhane I've tried your way but the difference is the tmp = callback from getTemplate I've added better styled fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5xebdabm/

Comment: Could you ammed it your way and can try to plug this in.

Comment: I think I need to help you through TeamViewer.

Comment: @HariLamichhane I can't send you private message so could you email me to: o696106@mvrht.com and I will reply to your email with the session id

Comment: I have sent mail.

Comment: Im glad it helped :)

Answer (score -2):

I guess you should  go for JSON if you want a variable to store an object. Then you can use JSON.parse() to parse and pull your information from JSON data. Please check w3schools.org for more detailed explanation. : )

Comment: If you're wondering why you're being downvoted, this is really more of a comment than an answer. Also recommending w3schools for any reason around here will get you a healthy number of downvotes pretty quickly. It's not such a reliable source.